# How to draw horizontal line with rubber length?

Tags: rules

The `\hrulefill` command could draw rubber length underlines, like `abc___def`. I just want to draw line in the vertical centre of a text, like `abc---def`. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`xhfill` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xhfill) provides different leader commands to do exactly this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xhfill}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xhfill
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
abc\xrfill{1pt}xyz \par
abc\xrfill[.5ex]{.4pt}xyz
\end{document}
```

Specifically regarding your question, `\xrfill[<raise>]{<width>}` prints a rule of width `<width>` raised `<raise>` from the baseline. Other leader options are also provided by the package. See the [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xhfill/xhfill-doc.pdf) for more examples.

For drawing a rule of specific (rather than rubber) length, you can always use a regular raised `\rule`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
abc\hspace{4cm}xyz \par
abc\raisebox{.5ex}{\rule{4cm}{.4pt}}xyz
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The command `\leaders` is intended for such things. In your case you can write

```
abc\leaders\hrule depth -2pt height 2.4pt\hskip 10pt plus 1fill xyz
```

to get a rule of height 0.4pt raised 2pt above the baseline with minimum width 10pt.

Comment: Thanks, but I think xhfill seems easier.

Comment: @YunHuang But `xhfill` only works in latex.