# A horizontal line with the same space-filling behaviour as /hfill?

Tags: spacing, packages

Is there a command or package which would allow me to draw a line in the largest available space in the way that `\hfill` fills up the remaining space in a line?

*i.e.*, a command to draw a line from the end of the text, wherever it happens to fall, to the right edge of the textwidth (leaving space for any additional text indented to be at the end of the line)?

Comment: See [How can I fill a line from the left?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154772/5764); [How to draw horizontal line with rubber length?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64600/5764)

Answer (score 21):

You can use ordinary `\hrulefill`. There is also `\dotfill` for dots. For advanced control `xhfill` may be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}      %% just to show the frame
\usepackage{xhfill}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

%% Usage
%% \xhrulefill{<color>}{<height>}
%% \xrfill[raise]{ruleheight}[color]
%% \xhrectanglefill{<height>}{<linewidth>}
%% \xhrectanglefill{1cm}{1pt}

First \verb|\xrfill|\xrfill{1pt}

This is \verb|\xrfill|\xrfill[0pt]{3pt}[blue]

A take with \verb|\xhrulefill|\xhrulefill{cyan}{1cm}

With \verb|\xhrectanglefill|\xhrectanglefill{0.5cm}{1pt}

%% Ordinary \hrulefill

With \verb|Ordinary \hrulefill|\hrulefill

With \verb|Ordinary \dotfill|\dotfill
\end{document}​
```

[image]