# Texts above and below one filling horizontal rule

Tags: positioning

Here is a starting code for a template to write sheets of exercises.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xhfill}   % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155960/6880
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

START

\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.2ex}
\framebox{Ex.1}\xrfill[0.4ex]{0.25ex}

\end{document}
```

I would like to add materials above and below the filling rule like in the following picture. How can I achieve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a zero-width box with content raised/lowered into position:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

START

\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.2ex}%
\framebox{Ex.1}\xrfill[0.4ex]{0.25ex}%
\makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{.5\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\scshape above}}%
\makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{-.6\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\scshape below}}%

\end{document}
```

The raised/lowered text is set with `0pt` height/depth so it doesn't affect the line spacing for surrounding content.

Comment: Thanks. I have to learn to play more seriously with boxes...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stackengine`'s top and bottom lapping macros.  Here `\tllap` is a top-left lap, and `\bllap` is a bottom-left lap.  The optional argument provides the baseline skip of the lap.  The `%` at line end is necessary to avoid stray spaces before or between laps.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xhfill}   % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155960/6880
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}

START

\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.2ex}
\framebox{Ex.1}\xrfill[0.4ex]{0.25ex}%
\tllap[6pt]{Here}%
\bllap[9pt]{and There}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shorter to write. Thanks for this short version.