# how to raise a hrulefill in header & footer

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to raise the `\hrulefill`, to arrange it with with bullet mark. Can anyone please help me to do this?

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{calc}
%
%        F        O        N        T
%
%\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{iwona}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath} 
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
%
%    M    A    R    G    I    N
%
\usepackage[left=15mm,right=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm,headheight=0mm,]{geometry}
%
%H    E    A    D    E    R,     F    O    O    T    E    R
%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[CO]{{\slshape{\hrulefill$\bullet$~\leftmark~$\bullet$\hrulefill~~\thepage}} } %MakeUppercase
\fancyhead[CE]{{\slshape{\thepage~~\hrulefill$\bullet$~\leftmark~$\bullet$\hrulefill}} }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} } 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} }
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%
%   S   T   A   R   T      D   O   C   U   M   E   N   T
%
\begin{document}
\chapter{My Story Name}
\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

blah\xrfill[1mm]{1pt}[red]blub
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related: [How to draw horizontal line with rubber length?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64600/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are loading [`xhfill`](//ctan.org/pkg/xhfill), so use it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xhfill}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\slshape\mbox{}\xrfill[.5ex]{.4pt}$\bullet$~\leftmark~$\bullet$\xrfill[.5ex]{.4pt}~~\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} 

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My Story Name}

\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext

\end{document}
```

You do need a starting reference - say, `\mbox{}` - in order for `\xrfill` to be useful.